# virtual web folder served by PHP script

Tags: php, scripting, virtualization

I am trying to configure my apache to be able to display (virtual) pages like:
mywebpage.com/something1
mywebpage.com/something2
mywebpage.com/folder/something3

I would like these "somethingX" and "folder" folders to be only virtual, not physical directories. For a start it would be great to send all requests to mywebpage to one PHP script which will somehow receive the original path information (there is some SERVER array as far as I know) and call necessary PHP functions (so far I use addresses like mywebpage.com/index.php?page=blabla&otherparameters=values...). Is that possible?

I am struggling with different combination, currently I am with following file in /etc/apache2/conf.d/something.conf (not working of course). What is the correct way to proceed? Thanks.

```
<Location /myweb>
SetHandler my-handler 
Action my-handler /srv/www/htdocs/myweb/product.php virtual
</Location>
```

My pages are in /srv/www/htdocs/myweb. I tried with Location, with Directory, with Action and SetHandler, with AddHandler... ;-) Some configurations were ignored, some caused "object not found" with nothing relevant in error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use mod_rewrite, create a file called `.htaccess` inside /myweb than redirect all request to php file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myweb
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* redirect.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

In redirect.php you can access the request path with: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: I am playing with this currently. Seems it is working fine for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: One more question. Almost everything works as expected, I only have problems with folders. Let's say I just do something like echo
    <img src="image.jpg"> 
in my redirect.php. When redirect goes from let's say mydomain.com/anything then it displays /myweb/image.jpg. But when address written is mydomain.com/folder/anything then it tries to display /myweb/folder/image.jpg which is not what i want. Can I change current dir to root somehow? I just want redirect eferything to redirect.php and read it in that $_SERVER variable.

Comment: I think you should look at the documentation of module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks. I did some small changes in apache configuration but mainly I had to changed my links from form "image/something.jpg" to form "/image/something.jpg". Everything is working fine now as far as I can see.